# Displaying an Image from a database and linking it to another page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to display images from a database, but I wanted these images that are being displayed
to be linked to another page where you can comment on them. While they are able to display without
the a href, the second I put it in, the images no longer show, and their is no error indicating why.

Here is the php

```
require("config.php");

$dbc = mysqli_connect ($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: '. mysqli_connect_error());

$sql = "SELECT * from image" ;
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or die ("Could not access DB: " . mysqli_error());

// Insert a back to browse button here?

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<div class=\"picture\">";
    echo "<p>";
    echo "<a href=\"comments.php?image={$row['image_id']}\"<img src=\"upload/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" /></a>";   
    echo $row['title'] . "<br />";
    echo "</div>";
}

    ?>
```

I'm assuming there is some syntax error here I am not realizing.

```
echo "<a href=\"comments.php?image={$row['image_id']}\"<img src=\"upload/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" /></a>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you were on the right tracks with that line - you're missing a > at the end of your opening a tag:

```
echo "<a href=\"comments.php?image={$row['image_id']}\"<img src=\"upload/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" /></a>";
```

Should be:

```
echo "<a href=\"comments.php?image={$row['image_id']}\"><img src=\"upload/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" /></a>";
```

(Look right before img if you can't see what's changed).

Comment: Omg your the best person ever, thank you! I knew it was something small like that!